# Integrated Terminal on VS Code Throwing Constant ZSH Error

Tags: python, visual-studio, terminal, zsh

I'm currently using VS Code with Python. No matter what I seem to do, when I type a command into terminal (even something simple like `print("hello")`), I get the following error: zsh: missing end of string

I've done some research online and can't find a good fix. I'm using Conda, but have also tried on the 'recommended' interpreter (Python 3.8.9 64-bit) and am having the same issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you pasted the entire terminal content as is/screenshot of the issue.